# NodeJS Project is Not Accessible By Other IPS

Tags: node.js, api, express

As an mobile developer I created a simple/mid-level API for my apps with NodeJS/ExpressJS.

I exported project on Linux VPS and enable access through domain like; ***myapp.com:5000/api/users...***

The problem is I am the only one(ip) who can access to this project. When I send a link to people like ***myapp.com:5000/get/user***, they are not able to open it.

Interestingly I can only have access through my Wifi (not accessible with mobile data) and I am using exported version not local ip adress. Do you suggest me anything?

Global:

```
app.use(express.json()); app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})); app.use(express.json());
```

Server-Side Codes:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
const error = new Error('Not Found!');
error.status = 404;
next(error);});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.json({message: "Unknown Server Error"});
```

});

```
module.exports = app.listen(5000, "0.0.0.0",() => console.log("Server Started on Port"));
```

I have tried different ports like 3000, 5000 but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

if you have hosted your API on server then use :

```
let port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(port, ()=>{
console.log("app is running on "+ port);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but this also didn't work. I have tried earlier. I see some "httpCreateServer" code piece, do you think I should use something like that?

Comment: Log says app is running on 5000, but still not accesible by other IPs.

Comment: Is there any CORS issue?

Comment: By the way, why are you using "module.exports" in " module.exports = app.listen(5000, "0.0.0.0",() => console.log("Server Started on Port"));"

Comment: I deleted that part, still same. I didn't get CORS error but anyway I used and enabled it but didn't work. The page simply doesn't response. Interestingly it works on my wifi even though its hosted on server

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution. It was tricky and easy. I had to set my firewall off from Centos Panel.